# error Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java

While converting the `InputStream` to `BufferedImage` I am getting the below error

```
byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decode(encodedStr);
```

This line is executing fine and generating the byte array properly

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes);
BufferedImage  bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

This line is giving error as it is unable to read the `InputStream` properly

```
Below is the error
    javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
      at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
      at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
      at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
      at DecodeSignatureFile.generateImage(DecodeSignatureFile.java:252)
      at DecodeSignatureFile.getContents(DecodeSignatureFile.java:176)
      at DecodeSignatureFile.process(DecodeSignatureFile.java:322)
      at DecodeSignatureFile.main(DecodeSignatureFile.java:334)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
      at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(Unknown Source)
      ... 8 more
```

Comment: Is it possible that your decoding method is wrong or **encodedStr** corrupted?

Comment: And what is `decoder`? You've given us *very* little information here.

Answer (score 0):

The error likely occurs before. In Java a String `encodedStr` is often not suitable to hold binary data. Compare those `imgBytes` to the original image.

Of course it depends on the encoding and decoding. But the rest looks okay.